# Having problems allocating memory in Objective C for a UILocalNotification

Tags: objective-c

If I do the following, it allocates the memory as expected:

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (!localNotification)
    NSLog(@"Huh?");
else
    NSLog(@"Okay");
```

However, I have a UILocalNotification as a field of another class called Task, and when I try to do the same thing with that field, it does not work:

```
currentTask.localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (!currentTask.localNotification)
    NSLog(@"Huh?");
else
    NSLog(@"Okay");
```

This also doesn't work, which would seem to betray an incomplete understanding of Objective C references on my part:

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [currentTask localNotification];
localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (!currentTask.localNotification)
    NSLog(@"Huh?");
else
    NSLog(@"Okay");
```

Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: `currentTask` is nil.

Comment: Whenever anything really weird happens in Objective-C it's usually because a pointer is nil.